# Who Bot for Microsoft Teams (Who knows about...)

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams

Added Who Bot in MS Teams but am unable to find a reliable and definitive answer on how I can "teach" the bot to answer the questions **"Who knows about ..."**

Some sources point to updating Delve account with skills, some say it will get that information from chat discussions in Teams... nothing works (after almost a month of the bot being added).

So, how can I feed the Who Bot information so that it can answer that specific question - **"Who knows about a topic"**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was talking to Microsoft about this. After weeks of back and forth, this is their conclusion:

> Thank you for your time over the phone today.
>
> As regards your concern, the Who Bot feature needs a different
> expertise to feed data for the “Who Bot” to fetch results for the
> queries on “who knows about”.
>
> This information needs to be fed into a text file with a scripting
> expert and then integrated into the Who Bot connector. This is where
> "who knows about" fetch its data from.
>
> Since we are only a break fix issues support team and do not work on
> scripting, this is out of our support boundaries.
>
> Ref articles and work items:
> • https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/12.customQABot
>
> Please, let me know if you have further concerns about this.
>
> Thank you for choosing Microsoft support

Their solutions was "please code a bot to fix our bot"

Comment: Appreciate the info Jeremy & Jeff. This is priceless :) - Their solutions was "please code a bot to fix our bot"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a question answering project from your own content, such as FAQs or product manuals.
This bot has been created using the Bot Framework SDK, it shows how to create a bot that uses [Cognitive Services' question answering feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/quickstart/sdk?pivots=studio).

[Question answering](https://language.cognitive.azure.com/) lets you to build, train and publish a simple question and answer bot based on FAQ URLs, structured and unstructured documents, or editorial content in minutes. In this sample, we demonstrate how to use question answering to answer questions based on an FAQ text file used as input.

Ref Sample-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/12.customQABot

Comment: Thanks for that information but that is not really what I asked. I am interested in where the Who bot, which is developed by Microsoft and advertised as specifically being able to answer the "who knows about" question expect to get its information from.